# QGridLayout, tight rows and columns without padding or spacing

Tags: c++, qt

I am using **QGridLayout**, the first row has a **QLabel** which is used to show an icon set to 32x32 pixels.  The next row has two **QSvgWidgets**, each of these is 16x14.

My code:

```
    QGridLayout* pgrdloStatus(new QGridLayout);
    if ( mplblStsIcon == nullptr )
    {
        mplblStsIcon = new QLabel();
    }  
    if ( mpsvgRxIcon == nullptr )
    {
        mpsvgRxIcon = new QSvgWidget(":/SVG_LED");
        mpsvgRxIcon->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        mpsvgRxIcon->setFixedSize(TraineeMonitor::mscuintCommsIconWidth,
                                  TraineeMonitor::mscuintCommsIconHeight);
    }
    if ( mpsvgTxIcon == nullptr )
    {
        mpsvgTxIcon = new QSvgWidget(":/SVG_LED");
        mpsvgTxIcon->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        mpsvgTxIcon->setFixedSize(TraineeMonitor::mscuintCommsIconWidth,
                                  TraineeMonitor::mscuintCommsIconHeight);
    }
    const QString cstrToolTip(QString(
            "   %1: %2\r\n%3: %4")
                    .arg(tr("Hostname:")).arg(mstrHostname)
                    .arg(tr("MAC address:")).arg(mstrMACaddress));
    mplblStsIcon->setToolTip(cstrToolTip);
    pgrdloStatus->addWidget(mplblStsIcon, 0, 0, 1, 2, Qt::AlignHCenter);
    pgrdloStatus->addWidget(mpsvgRxIcon, 1, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
    pgrdloStatus->addWidget(mpsvgTxIcon, 1, 1, Qt::AlignRight);
    pgrdloStatus->setMargin(0);
    pgrdloStatus->setSpacing(0);
    return pgrdloStatus;
```

The result:
[image: 8ce2f5ce-c68d-4064-a4e7-c0e3f97ee65f-image.png]
What I actually want is:
[image: 99d2e764-0816-42bf-90f0-76356b1ba7fa-image.png]

Comment: Maybe, the `pgrdloStatus` is stretched by the layout (or widget) it's added to. So, you have to care of the outer layout (or widget) that it doesn't do so (e.g. by adding a spacer or giving something else the opportunity to stretch).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, thank you, will look into this now.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, it actually look like the column spanning isn't working at all, because in the image each column occupies its own column.  Row 0 occupies column 1 and although the last icon I set to 1, 1, it occupies column 2.

Comment: try flip alignment to see.. from code it's not so. just two columns are stretched wide enough and those widgets are aligned to outer sides (left one to the left, right one to the right)

Comment: I cant compile your code because you use lots of things that didn't put here. Please  provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it

Comment: @Parisa.H.R, this layout is added to a QHBoxLayout, thats the only thing missing.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, alignments changed over now its perfect, thank you!

Comment: you didn't need QSvgWidget for adding Svg file to label , if you `setPixmap` label and put its source SVG file it does it for you. but in `.pro` file you should set `QT+=svg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create this Example and add Items From the Designer to show you why you see that distance between icons.

I create GridLayout and put 2 labels and set 2 LED SVG image

this is what actually you do too :

[image]

**But For Fixing this issue you should check this property :**

**which means this :**  `label->setScaledContents(true);`

[image]

**Which means that your icons match to labels.**

For removing margins of GridLay out you can also do this :

[image]

**This is its code:**

```
#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QLabel *label;
    QLabel *label_2;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(207, 109);
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(centralwidget);
        gridLayout->setSpacing(0);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        label = new QLabel(centralwidget);
        label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/icons/led-square-red.svg")));
        label->setScaledContents(true);

        gridLayout->addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        label_2 = new QLabel(centralwidget);
        label_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_2"));
        label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/icons/led-square-red.svg")));
        label_2->setScaledContents(true);

        gridLayout->addWidget(label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", nullptr));
        label->setText(QString());
        label_2->setText(QString());
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```